# UV export problem

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am new to Blender.  I found an object I need to for a project online.

My problem is that when I export it as a .OBJ I need the textures/materials and to be saved a .PNG to drop into a game engine.

When I export the layout from the UV editor screen it comes with the seams on it, Ive been looking around constantly but can't seem to find a solution on how to export this properly (If at all). I have attached the .PNG for reference.

I have tried to bake the materials onto a new image to then use a texture but when I do it comes out half black and not filled in.

Any help or clarification is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the Image -> Save As Image or the UV -> Export UV Layout ? The  second one will always include the seams.

Comment: I was using Export UV layout, Ill try save as image.  Thanks!